# Can I change the handset software operator?

Tags: rom-flashing, rom, htc-one-x

I have an HTC One X on the Orange network here in the UK.

I sent my phone off for repair due to a bad screen. When it has come back 3 weeks later it seems to have been reloaded with T-Mobile software! My old Sim card will not work as it says it is network locked, and is asking for an 8 character unlock code.

Orange say I need to send it away for repair again to get this fixed, but I wondered if I could somehow change the software back to the standard UK Orange version suitable for this phone.

I don't want to jailbreak it or anything like that, just get the Orange software on it instead of the T-Mobile software.

Is this something I can easily do, or should I just bite the bullet and send it away for another 3 weeks?

Comment: It will be much faster to send it in again. Re-Branding will most likely cause you some trouble, as it involves "root-stuff" (most "branding-files" are located in partitions which a "normal user" only has read access to, such as e.g. `/system`). I'd blame the repair shop and have them sending a replacement in advance/parallel to shorten the wait time -- after all, it's their fault.